# Can you use a REST API as a replacement to a conventional DB in YII?

Tags: php, yii

I know [YII supports various databases](http://learnyii.blogspot.com/2011/08/yii-php-database-postgres-mysql-sqlite.html), but with the current project I am working on, YII won't be connecting to conventional database. Checking if a username is valid and even registering a new user is done via a REST API.

As a noob to YII, please help me understand:

1. Can YII be set up to use my custom rest api?
2. Will commands like $model->validate() work if it's not really talking to a conventional database?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an [active resource extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/activeresource) that serves this purpose. it behaves like conventional active record, but instead of using a relational database it uses a restful end.